# A toolbar não esta aparecendo

Tags: java, android

Eu estou fazendo um app para o meu tcc e resolvi colocar um menu lateral no app, o menu funciona, mas onde fica a toolbar aparece apenas uma faixa preta sem ícone e eu coloquei um ícone de menu hambúrguer.

estou usando o android studio 1.4, a toolbar tem algum problema nessa versão?

main.java

```
...

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
            setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

     
            ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
                if (actionBar != null) {
                    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
                    actionBar.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_menu);
                }

        
            mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
            NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
            navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(menuSelection);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_drawer, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            //Clique no ícone hamburger de menu, para a abertura do drawer
            case android.R.id.home:
                mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    private NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener menuSelection = new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
            menuItem.setChecked(true);
            switch (menuItem.getItemId()){
                
            }
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();
            return false;
        }
    };
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".TelaPrincipal">


        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">


            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                android:elevation="4dp"
                android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="194dp"
                android:id="@+id/imageView"
                android:src="@drawable/logo_llga2"
                android:layout_marginLeft="0dp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:text="BEM VINDO"
                android:id="@+id/tv_bem_vindo"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
                android:textColor="#061af6" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="criar um novo relatório"
                android:id="@+id/button"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:onClick="entrar_clique" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="ENVIAR RELATÓRIO"
                android:id="@+id/button5"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:onClick="enviar_clique" />

        </LinearLayout>


        <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
            android:id="@+id/nav_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            app:menu="@menu/menu_drawer"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

style.xml

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>

<style
    name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
    parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

<style
    name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
    parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```

adicionei isso tambem no AndroidManifest.xml

```
android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
```

Comment: Tem certeza que a versão é 1.4? Porque essa é uma bem velha. A versão atual estável é a 4.1

Answer (score 0):

Tem vários pontos a serem corrigidos aí:

Se você está usando `android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">` no AndroidManifest.xml, não importa nada do que você fez no styles.xml Porque o app vai usar a o tema padrão. Para usar o tema que está declarado no seu styles.xml, use `android:theme="@style/AppTheme"`.

Você nem precisa editar nada no styles.xml, a não ser que você queira mudar pra tema escuro ou algo assim. O arquivo que vem quando você cria o projeto já é uma boa base.

Você não precisa criar uma `Toolbar` no seu XML se você usa o tema `<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">`, que, como o nome já diz, traz uma action bar pra você. Para usar essa action bar que já vem, é só chamar `getSupportActionBar()` na sua activity.

O fato de ter ficado tudo preto talvez tenha a ver com o as linhas `android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"` e `app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"`, mas se você usar a action bar padrão, isso provavelmente vai se resolver.